# Test for maximum difference in means across different samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have a set of N different samples with T observations each, i.e., $y_1 = (y_{11}, ..., y_{1T})^\top$ to $y_N = (y_{N1}, ..., y_{NT})^\top$. I suspect one of these samples has a much larger mean than the rest and want to develop a statistical test to check for that.

I started with the t-statistic for a difference in means test.
$$
T_{ij} = \frac{\bar{y}_i - \bar{y}_j}{\sqrt{s_i^2 / T + s_j^2 / T}}
$$
where $s_i^2$ and $s_j^2$ are the sample variances.

I did this for each pair $(i,j)$ and then took that maximum t-statistic
$$
T^* = \max_{ij} T_{ij}.
$$
This seemed like a relatively straight-forward idea, but I am really struggling with what distribution $T^*$ would follow. I know by construction the $T_{ij}$ cannot be iid normal or t distributions. I also have good reason to believe the samples aren't iid either.

Any thoughts on the approach or other ideas to consider? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Tukey HSD" might be a good topic to look up.  "Studentized range" may also be helpful.

Comment: You might start with an ANOVA to see if there really are significant differences in means among the $N$ groups. If the null hypothesis (all are same) is indeed rejected, then Tukey HSD is an excellent way to discover the pattern of differences without risking 'false discovery' of particular differences.

Comment: Thanks!! I knew someone must have thought of something like this. I guess my Googling skills weren't good enough to uncover Tukey's test.